# How to print the sequence 3 7 13 17 23 ...upto 100 in java

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop

It want the sequence like: `3 7 13 17 23 27 33 37 ....up to 100`
but I am getting the following output:

```
3 13 23 33..
7 17 27 37
```

code is:

```
class abc extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        int i;
        for(i=3; i<97; i+=10)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                try
                { sleep(100);}
                catch(Exception e){}
            }
        for(i=7; i<97; i+=10)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                try
                { sleep(100);}
                catch(Exception e){}
            }
    }
}
    class Print3n7n13n17
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            abc p= new abc();
            abc p1= new abc();
            p.start();
            p1.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's the whole point of threads. They execute concurrently. If you want to print a sequence, you should use sequential code.

Comment: The sequence is `+4 +6 +4 +6` and you're adding `+10 +10 +10`. Why isn't it not strange that your code doesn't work?

Comment: Thinking about how to solve the problem is absolutely wrong.I think you should go through how multithreading works.The problem doesnt even require multithreading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since nothing is your question says you have to use two threads, why not make it simple?

```
    for(i=3; i<97; i+=10)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(i+4);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int start = 3
while(start < 97)
{
    //Print the number
    System.out.println(start);
    //The next number is greater than its previous by 4
    start = start+4;
    System.out.println(start);
    //And then it increments by 6
    start = start+6;
}
```